# Rails - using form_for tag with different methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have index method in my Admin controller:

```
def index
  @news = News.all
end
```

on index page i want to see all the news,but how i can create news from same page (index) if

```
form_for @news
```

wont work because @news = News.all ?

Comment: do you need create  and index in same page?? if so do check how to use partials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a new `News` object, and use that for the form.

```
def index
  @news = News.all
  @new_news = News.new
end
```

In the view,

```
form_for @new_news
```

Answer (score 0):

Use partials 
Put the create form in the index page as partial and in create use a different instance variable.